# Modal Segue but I need a Present Modally

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am forced to ask this in desperation - I have searched high and low.
My problem is simple - Xcode will only offer me segues modal while I need  "Present Modally". In one section of the app it allows this but not in others.
Obviously I must be missing a setting.

Comment: OS X? iOS? Please explain your issue with more details and context.

Comment: IOS - sorry
When I create a segue Xcode only offers me deprecated (I think) modal segue. I need to use Presented Modally however I cannot change kind from modal to Present Modally. All I am doping in this part of the app is using a button with a segue to an NC which has a VC embedded. This VC has an image view linking to Photo Library and Camera. The modal segue appears to not trigger the privacy requests - at least not on an iPhone 4s.
I am sure its a setting but I can't find any guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take(Select) that view which you can't present modally. Now go to the Editor 'embed in' that with navigationController. It will work

Comment: No that did not do it I still only get to choose Modal
The strange thing is if a create a new project and take just this section of the app I then can get the Presented option - I assume there must be a setting somewhere that IU have overlooked

Comment: there is not any setting you need to check the segue property. click on segue and go to the attribute inspector there must be kind selected as  "Present modally"

Comment: Thanks  but it does not give me that choice on this particular segue - very frustrating.

Comment: Ok Now i Got your problem.. wait I am posting in comment

Comment: from where you are dragging line to make segue??

Comment: Hi I am dragging from a button which is in a table row in a table view of static cells. - I drag from there to the NC which is linked to a VC in the normal way i.e. root view controller

Comment: The strange thing is if I simulate a similar scenario in a fresh project it does not seem to occur. so my guess is I might have  bug in the project file.

Comment: drag it from the viewController (yellowSymbol) and than in your button action write code :: PerformSegueWithidentifire("")

Comment: Thank you - that sounds like the answer

Answer (score 0):

In the end the answer was simple Under file inspector tick "Use Size Classes". I had un-ticked these while developing.